# Concept of Private class in C#

Tags: c#, .net, access-modifiers

Can private classes exist in C#, other than in Inner classes?

Answer (score 70):

Simply NO. Nothing unless its in a nested Class

- Classes and structs that are not nested within other classes or structs can be either **public** or **internal**. A type declared as public is accessible by any other type. A type declared as internal is only accessible by types within the same assembly. Classes and structs are declared as **internal by default** unless the keyword public is added to the class definition.
- Class or struct definitions can add the internal keyword to make their access level explicit. Access modifiers do not affect the class or struct itself — it always has access to itself and all of its own members.
- Struct members, including nested classes and structs, can be declared as public, internal, or private. Class members, including nested classes and structs, can be public, protected internal, protected, internal, or private. The access level for class members and struct members, including nested classes and structs, is private by default. Private nested types are not accessible from outside the containing type.
- Derived classes cannot have greater accessibility than their base types. In other words, you cannot have a public class B that derives from an internal class A. If this were allowed, it would have the effect of making A public, because all protected or internal members of A are accessible from the derived class.

  ---

  You can enable specific other assemblies to access your internal types by using the [**InternalsVisibleToAttribute**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx).

Answer (score 23):

No, there isn't. You cannot have a private class unless it is nested.

Answer (score 5):

In what scenario other then for an innter class would you like to have a 'private' class ?

You can use the `internal` modifier to create a class that is only visible in the current assembly.

```
// the class below is only visible inside the assembly in where it was declared
internal class MyClass
{
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No.
What would the scope of such a class be?

Comment: I'd guess OP is more experienced in Java, which would allow visibility within the same source file.

Answer (score 2):

We can declare a class as Private inside other class. kindly find the code below on how to achieve the same:

```
 public class Class1
  {
    temp _temp ;
    public Class1()
    {
      _temp = new temp();   
    }    

    public void SetTempClass(string p_str, int p_Int)
    {
      _temp.setVar(p_str, p_Int);
    }

    public string GetTempClassStr()
    {
      return _temp.GetStr();
    }

    public int GetTempClassInt()
    {
      return _temp.GetInt();
    }

    private class temp
    {
      string str;
      int i;

      public void setVar(string p_str, int p_int)
      {
        str = p_str;
        i = p_int;
      }

      public string GetStr()
      {
        return str;
      }

      public int GetInt()
      {
        return i;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Answer copied from here - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ffa250ea-cb88-4a17-a1fe-876997dfa96f/private-class-in-c?forum=csharplanguage

Answer (score 2):

C# 11 added [file-local types](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-11.0/file-local-types). Types with the `file` access modifier are only available within the source file where they are declared.

For example, you can declare a file-local class `Foo` in one file:

```cs
// file1.cs
namespace Test;

file class Foo {}

class FooFactory
{
    public static object CreateFoo() => new Foo();
}
```

In another file you cannot refer to the type by the name `Foo`:

```cs
// file2.cs

using System;

namespace Test;

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
         // Prints something like:
         // "Test.<file1>EF2345065A04F90B2A4EE01E86C4DF23B0AF1B96D7D3F7CC9046D1F1C5EADFB80__Foo"
         Console.WriteLine(FooFactory.CreateFoo());
         // Does not compile with error:
         // "The type or namespace name 'Foo' could not be found"
         new Foo();
    }
}
```

As you can see from this example, the C# compiler gives each file-local class a unique name when compiled. This allow multiple files to define a file-local class with the same name and not interfere with each other at run time.