# Inconsistent accessibility strange error

Tags: c#

I have this below piece of code which makes me puzzling about internals of a private class. I could see many search results for this error, still the below sounds wierd

```
namespace X
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static XYZ sample1;
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XYZ sample2 = new XYZ(); // OK  (1)
            sample1 = new XYZ();  // NOK    (2)
                    ...
        }
    }

    private class XYZ
    {

    }
}
```

If class XYZ is private, how does it work at (1) but not in (2)?

Comment: Does this even compile ? even if you remove your *NOK* code

Comment: Off the top of my head, I'm surprised either of those work.  I didn't even know you can have a `private` class not as a nested class.  EDIT: Yeah, of course it doesn't compile (tested in LINQPad). Can you post the _actual_ code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906546/concept-of-private-class-in-c-sharp agrees with @ChrisSinclair too

Comment: @V4Vendetta: Yeah it compiles when i remove (2) and sample1 declaration.

Comment: Yeah, I think Tomas Voracek has it.  The code posted is incorrect, but essentially @inquisitive is exposing a private class for public consumption which is not possible.  inquisitive would have to make the class public (or choose not to expose it).

Comment: Strange non of the answers below mention that a private class won't work as shown above :(

Comment: @V4Vendetta they figured out what the actual state of inquisitive's code is based on the error message.  Yeah, the posted code isn't 100% correct, but that's not the question. (though it doesn't help)

Comment: @All: Thanks for your answers. Finally i made sample1 as Internal and it worked. Now only my Unit testing assembly will have access to Sample1 and no outsiders have access, which was my intention :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works in both (1) and (2):

```
// OK, you declare and assign a local variable of a known type
XYZ sample2 = new XYZ();

// OK, you assign a static field of a known type
sample1 = new XYZ();
```

You can't declare `public static XYZ sample1;` at all because it's public when XYZ is private:

```
// This won't compile if XYZ is private
public static XYZ sample1;
```

This makes sense, users of `X.Program` will have access to its public members (in this case `sample1`) but they won't be able to use them because `XYZ` is private to the assembly (then not accessible). That's why the compiler says "inconsistent accessibility".

Answer (score 2):

It is because you are exposing

```
public static XYZ sample1;
```

member to be visible from other code outside of 'X' namespace. But class XYZ is marked as private, thus the error. So nothing strange here.